# "Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target" Error on iOS7 and below

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uialertcontroller

Hi I'm migrating old iOS project I got this error from my new line of code from helper class `ApiManager.m` (a network call)

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NO_INTERNET_ERROR_TITLE message:TRACKED_ITEM_NOT_FOUND_ERROR preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
[alert addAction:ok];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The error is:

> 016-08-16 13:52:49.955 SingPost[967:60b] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application
>   tried to present a nil modal view controller on target
>   .'

The problem only occur on iOS 7 and below. From version 8 and above nothing wrong. How to fix this? Any help is much appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per iOS version you should make use of UIAlertView and UIAlertController:

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0"))
 {
   alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Invalid Coupon."  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
 }
        else
       {
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController    alertControllerWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Invalid Coupon." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


        UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                   {

                                   }];

        [alertController addAction:okAction];

        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem occur on IOS 7 because `UIAlertController` as a doc says
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/

> Available in iOS 8.0 and late

For iOS 7 you need use `UIAlertView`

Comment: Thanks for your info. Should we still support IOS 7 at the moment. Should I move development target to 8.0?

Comment: If you stop support users with iOS 7 I think yes, you can change development target to 8.0

Comment: I mean should we keep code to support IOS7 or stop support completely (change target to 8.0)? at Aug2016? Are there many user with iOS 7?

Comment: It's only your choice. How many users with iOS 7 in you app I don't know. You need look your apps analytics for this. It various for diffrents apps. You can look it in iTunes connect how many users in ios7